# Why Flickr api working for only some amount of time

Tags: android, flickr

I am trying to access **public feed** via
https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne
which I get from
https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/docs/photos_public/
but It says "**Flickr API:Page not found**"
so how to proceed?
(note:**api works sometimes!**)

Answer (score 0):

The limit is 3.600 request per hour

https://www.flickr.com/services/developer/api/

Comment: If I am making an app that uses this,then how to handle this now?